# godaddy subfolder domain htaccess redirect without changing browser url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

Godaddy Deluxe Hosting with Linux

Main domain: www.domain1.com & 2 other hosted domains (www.domain2.com and www.domain3.com) are in subfolders

The contents of www.domain2.com .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule shop/tackle/(.*)/(.*)/ https://www.domain2.com/shop/products.php?subcat_id=$1&subcat2_id=$2 [NC]
```

This will direct www.domain2.com/shop/tackle/1/0/
TO
www.domain2.com/shop/products.php?subcat_id=1&subcat2_id=0

but changes the url. I do understand that is because I'm includeing the https://www.domain2.com in the rewrite. However I try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule shop/tackle/(.*)/(.*)/ shop/products.php?subcat_id=$1&subcat2_id=$2 [NC]
```

I get a 404 error. I does indicate that URL /domain2/shop/tackle/1/0/ can't be located.

Obviously the rewrite is including the domain2 folder name. I'm trying to keep the requested URL www.domain2.com/shop/tackle/1/0/ in the URL.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have each domain pointing to correct DocumentRoot. as example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain2.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain3.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain3"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I don't think how the /domain2/ would be added onto relative request. But, if it is, then you should try RewriteBase directive to help with relative substitution is built correct. Like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule shop/tackle/(.*)/(.*)/ shop/products.php?subcat_id=$1&subcat2_id=$2 [NC]
```

This link has more information:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: Thanks Xiao Xing, but I have tried this and still get the 404 error. And notice that it now states: The requested URL /domain2/domain2/shop/products.php was not found on this server. Do I maybe need to move this rewrite to the .htaccess file in root dir under domain1 instead of in the domain2 subfolder?

Comment: It sound like you do not have dedicated document root defined for www.domain2.com. I think you should. Some thing else seems it maps request for `/shop/...` to `/domain2/shop/` Do you know what other setting? maybe an Alias or another Rewrite?

Comment: Playing with the RewriteBase directive did solve the problem

Comment: Still good to consider dedicated Document root and Virtualhost for each of domains, but good that RewriteBase gives workaround. Kindly accept answer if this fixed issue. Thank